# Adding grouping in framing clause window while creating partitions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

Using the dataset hosted on Google ([MBL Data](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/sportradar-public-data/mlb-pitch-by-pitch)) as an example, here is what I am accomplishing to do - obtain last 3 weeks score run for a given Venue.

My aggregated dataset looks like this without the strikes_3wk column -
[image]

Logic for strikes_3wk column is to partition the aggregated dataset by venueName, order by YearWeek column and then obtain the last 3 weeks aggregated strikes data.

Here is the query I have written so far. I see that the windowing function is where I need to modify the logic. So, is there a way to add grouping within the windowing function? Is there any alternative way of doing this?

In the image I added a new column 'expected', showing values for two weeks.

```
select inr.*
       ,sum(inr.strikes) over (Venue_Week rows between current row and 2 following) as strikes_3wk
from
(
    select seasonType
        ,gameStatus
        ,homeTeamName
        ,awayTeamName
        ,venueName
        ,CAST(
        CONCAT(
            CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM createdAt) as string)
            ,CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK(Monday) FROM createdAt) as string)
            ) as INT64)
            as YearWeek
        ,sum(homeFinalRuns) as homeFinalRuns
        ,sum(strikes) as strikes
    from  `bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_wide`
    where   createdAt is not null
    group by seasonType
        ,gameStatus
        ,homeTeamName
        ,awayTeamName
        ,venueName
        ,YearWeek
)inr
window Venue_Week as (
    partition by inr.venueName
    order by inr.YearWeek desc
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for strikes per venue regardless of who did them, right?

May be something like:

```sql
SELECT INR.*, STATS.strikes_3wk 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_wide` INR
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT venueName, SUM(strikes) as strikes_3wk 
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_wide` INR2
    WHERE YearWeek IN (
      SELECT TOP 3 YearWeek 
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_wide` 
      WHERE venueName = INR2.venueName
      ORDER BY YearWeek DESC
    )
    GROUP BY venueName
  ) STATS 
    ON INR.venueName = STATS.venueName
```

Comment: Thanks Umbreto for giving me some idea on how to tackle the problem. Actually, venues and weeks vary and not same across all. Hence the need for logic in windowing function. Am still working on it.

Comment: @VKarthik updated to calculate last 3 weeks per venue